# Showing ObservableCollection item changes using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, observablecollection, community-toolkit-mvvm

I went through SO questions on this topic and thought I followed the examples carefully but I still don't see a UI update when a property of an item in a `CollectionView` gets updated.

First, I made sure the property in my model is decorated with `ObservableProperty`:

```cs
public partial class Student : ObservableObject
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   [ObservableProperty]
   bool isRegistered; 
}
```

I then use an `ObservableCollection` in my view model which is also decorated with `ObservableProperty`:

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      var student = new Student
      {
          Id = 123,
          Name = "John Doe",
          IsRegistered = false
      };
      Students.Add(student);
      student = new Student
      {
          Id = 234,
          Name = "Jane Doe",
          IsRegistered = false
      };
      Students.Add(student);
   }

   [ObservableProperty]
   ObservableCollection<Student> students = new();

   [RelayCommand]
   void UpdateRegistrations()
   {
      foreach(var item in Students)
         item.IsRegistered = true;
   }
}
```

Here's the XAML:

```xml
<ContentPage...>
   <Grid
      RowDefinitions="*,50">

      <CollectionView
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
               x:DataType="model:Student">
               <Grid
                  ColumnDefinitions="*,30">
                  <Label
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  <Image
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Source="checkmark.png"
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsRegistered}" />
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>

      <Button
         Grid.Row="1"
         Text="Update Data"
         Command="{Binding UpdateRegistrationsCommand}" />

   </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

I don't see the change in `IsRegistered` reflected in the UI after executing `UpdateRegistrations()`. What am I missing here? I'm under the impression that CommunityToolkit.Mvvm handles `INotifyPropertyChanged` logic. Do I need to handle the change manually?

Comment: Where is the relevant XAML?

Comment: Nothing fancy going on in the XAML but updated the original post with the XAML code.

Comment: If you default the value to true does it show?

Comment: If I set the default value to `true`, the `Image` shows. I also reversed the logic so that when the `Button` is tapped, I set `IsRegistered` to `false`. Again, the UI doesn't reflect the change.

Comment: What you've done should work; you are correct that ObservableObject/ObservableProperty should propagate that update to UI. Seems suspiciously like a bug with IsVisible. As a test, add another element that is affected by IsRegistered, but not involving IsVisible: `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsRegistered}" />`. SIDE NOTE: Does `IsVisible={Binding IsRegistered}` even compile? I'm used to seeing double-quotes.

Comment: Sam, please read the comment I’ve added to the accepted answer. That answer has a partially incorrect description. Don’t want you misled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ObservableCollection` doesn't need the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute; it [automatically invokes `NotifyPropertyChanged` and `NotifyCollectionChanged` when you call its methods like `.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN). That's kinda the whole reason we use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` for MVVM.
2. In .NET MAUI (and Xamarin), View Model properties used for bindings must be a public non-static property, so we'll promote `Students` from a field to a read-only property (aka add `{ get; }` ).
3. In the XAML, the `DataTemplate` bindings are using incorrect syntax: the `Name` binding is missing the `Binding` keyword, and both should be wrapped in double-quotes (`"`). These bugs should be invoking a compiler (syntax) error when [`XAMLC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/xaml/xamlc) is enabled, so make sure you haven't accidentally disabled `XAMLC`.

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      Students.Add(new Student
      {
          Id = 123,
          Name = "John Doe",
          IsRegistered = false
      });

      Students.Add(new Student
      {
          Id = 234,
          Name = "Jane Doe",
          IsRegistered = false
      });
   }

   public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; } = new();

   [RelayCommand]
   void UpdateRegistrations()
   {
      foreach(var item in Students)
         item.IsRegistered = true;
   }
}
```

```xml
<ContentPage...>
   <Grid
      RowDefinitions="*,50">

      <CollectionView
         Grid.Row="0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
               x:DataType="model:Student">
               <Grid
                  ColumnDefinitions="*,30">
                  <Label
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Text="{Binding Name}" />
                  <Image
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Source="checkmark.png"
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsRegistered}" />
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      </CollectionView>

      <Button
         Grid.Row="1"
         Text="Update Data"
         Command="{Binding UpdateRegistrationsCommand}" />

   </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: "3" is the actual bug fix. 1 and 2 are moot. [ObservableProperty] does the equivalent. Also, 1’s explanation is partially wrong. ObservableCollection DOES NOT call NotifyPropertyChanged when `.Add`. That add does not change the value of the property; the property still points to the same collection. The only special feature of ObservableCollection is its NotifyCollectionChanged. [In fact, if code never does Add/Remove/etc, instead REPLACING the entire collection whenever there is a change, then List works just as well. There are some use cases where replacement is better performance.]